# Efficiently incrementing value by condition on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply

I have a pandas dataframe where I would like to compare the values in `Var1` and `Var2`

```
import pandas as pd 
  
data = [['foo', 'foo', 1613030200], \
        ['foo', 'foo', 1613030300], ['foo', 'bar', 1613030400], \
        ['foo', 'foo', 1613030500], ['foo', 'foo', 1613030600], ['bar', 'foo', 1613030700],\
        ['foo', 'foo', 1613030800], ['foo', 'foo', 1613030900], ['foo', 'foo', 1613030985]] 
   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Var1', 'Var2', 'ts']) 
   
df
```

The idea is to add a separate column called `group` that will increment by 1 only when a change is detected between `Var1` and `Var2` over time (starting from the earliest timestamp).

The output would look something like this:

```
    Var1    Var2    ts  group
0   foo foo 1613030200  0
1   foo foo 1613030300  0
2   foo bar 1613030400  1
3   foo foo 1613030500  1
4   foo foo 1613030600  1
5   bar foo 1613030700  2
6   foo foo 1613030800  2
7   foo foo 1613030900  2
8   foo foo 1613030985  2
```

I have tried using a lambda function to increment, though this throws an error:

```
counter = 0
df[['Var1','Var2']].apply(lambda x: counter +=1 if x['Var1']!=x['Var2'] else counter, axis=1)
```

Is there an efficient method of incrementing over rows by conditions that involve checking multiple columns in python (without a for loop)?  In SQL, the equivalent could be done with a window function such as:

```
SUM(
 CASE WHEN Var1 <> Var2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS group
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like just a `cumsum`:

```
df['groups'] = df['Var1'].ne(df['Var2']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
  Var1 Var2          ts  groups
0  foo  foo  1613030200       0
1  foo  foo  1613030300       0
2  foo  bar  1613030400       1
3  foo  foo  1613030500       1
4  foo  foo  1613030600       1
5  bar  foo  1613030700       2
6  foo  foo  1613030800       2
7  foo  foo  1613030900       2
8  foo  foo  1613030985       2
```